# Trouble with FilePickers in Unity Hololens development

Tags: unity-game-engine, runtime, hololens, filepicker

I found a terrific reference on [how to get started with file pickers](http://longqian.me/2017/02/08/hololens-file-transfer/). But with that being said, I am not able to get the provided code working for my Unity Hololens app.

My scenario:
I've a file, lets say an object file, like such, 3DModel.obj. I want my app to be able to locate this file (3DModel.obj) at runtime, and then load it at runtime.

I'm attempting to use these read/write functions but I'm getting no where. I've run through numerous functions such as, Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder, KnownFolder, LocalFolder, dataPath, persistentDataPath.

I've perused through [Microsofts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers#pick-a-single-file-step-by-step) file picker documentation, and I'm still left scratching my head.

None of these seem to accomplish what I'm trying to do, or my ineptitude and lack of knowledge on how to use file pickers fails to get the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Limitations of the HoloLens shell](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/current_limitations_for_apps_using_apis_from_the_shell):

> **File Explorer and Local File System**
>
> The Windows Holographic app model does not currently expose the concept of a file system. There are known folders, but there is no built in, local File Explorer app like on Windows Desktop or Mobile. Apps can save files to their local state folders. Apps can also save files to a registered File Picker app like OneDrive.

Comment: Can apps access saved files from OneDrive or local folders? Or can they strictly only save? Perhaps a better question... Is there a place to put files on my desktop so that I can access them on the app at runtime?

Comment: @JHiggins I haven't tried, honestly. None of the projects I've done so far have needed file system access and I do not currently have access to the device or emulator.